# Unable to create print job: 0x00000bbb

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printer, windows-10-v1903

after the Windows 10 Feature Update 1903 we've got at least 2 PCs (different printer manufactures and connection types) with this error:

Unable to create print job: 0x00000bbb

**PrinterA**

- Model: HP CLJ 400 (Laser Printer only)
- Connection: Shared Network Printer
- PC1: Windows Version 10.0.18362.535 / NOT working
- PC2: Windows Version 10.0.18362.356 / working

PC1 has the same Printer ("PrinterA") twice (one for black/white and one for colored prints), the "colored" one works, the "black/white" not. Same IP, same driver, same server.

On PC2, both variations of "PrinterA" (black/white and colored) were working.

For me, all settings seems to look identical. The printers are shared by the same server and deployed per Group Policy Extensions - so it should be the same on the client.

All tips I have found didn't helped so far: Comparing Registry Entries with one of the working PCs, Removing printers and drivers, settings rights with cacls.exe, deleting Registry Keys. I don't list them here because i have my doubts that they are really related to this problem.

So then there is one other Computer with this error. This one is located in a homeoffice, so it is completely different (other brand, model, manual installation, USB connected):

**PrinterB**

- Model: KONICA MINOLTA magicolor 1690MF (Laser Printer with Fax/Scan)
- Connection: USB
- PC3: Windows Version 10.0.18362.356 / NOT working

So I don't think that this problem is related to the printer (model). 
I think the update screwed it up at some point. 
But I'm lost, any ideas?

Regards, 
Stefan

EDIT1:

**PrinterA, network, black/white**:
Today, for the problematic network printer  I've created another port(name) for the IP on the printserver and shared it under a slighlty different name - and it works.

But I would like to know the root cause, I don't want to rename my printers after each Windows Feature Update...

**PrinterB, USB**
This one is driving me nuts. 
I removed all drivers, cleaned up the registry, rebooted and connected it via LAN and gave him a new name - but same error message :-(

Answer (score 0):

If this happens for all printing from all software on the affected computers,
this rare issue might have been caused by the Windows 10 update.
The problem in this case is that permissions have been lost on the print spooler
folder.

To correct:

- Start a Command Prompt (cmd.exe) as Administrator
- Run the commands:

  ```
  cd \Windows\System32\spool
  cacls.exe PRINTERS /E /G administrator:C
  ```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help. I can see that an 0-byte FP00000.SPL file is created by SYSTEM that stucks there till restart of the spooler service.

Comment: Do both computers have the same Printer twice?

Comment: Yes. (Both have also another printer twice with same constellation [colored, black/white] - and these are both working.)

Comment: Do there exist other computers on the same Windows version and with the same printers twice, but where it works?

Comment: No, this problem starts with the feature upgrade to version 1903, all computers still on 1809 can print without problem.

Comment: There have been driver architecture changes in version 1903 which might account for the problem. What printer is that?

Comment: PrinterA: HP Color LaserJet 400, HP Universal Printing PCL 6 driver version v6.6.0, PrinterB: KONICA MINOLTA magicolor 1690MF, driver version 2.2.5.0

Comment: Your drivers are indeed the "latest", but cannot be called "new". I suggest in Devices and Printers to right click the printer and choose Troubleshoot. Another possibility is to setup a Windows computer of a version for which the printer works as a network print server, which will avoid renaming it. (I don't dare suggest buying newer hardware.)